# Jittering motion in 3d snake game using lists in c# with unity3D

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am experiencing jittery movement in my 3D snake clone.

This is the code:

```
//movement
private Rigidbody rb;
public float force;
public float turnspeed;

//spawning
public int spawndelay;
public GameObject segment;
private List<Vector3> lastpos = new List<Vector3>();
private List<Quaternion> lastrotation = new List<Quaternion>();
private List<GameObject> segments = new List<GameObject>();




private int i = 1;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    StartCoroutine(spawnseg());
}

private void Update()
{
    lastpos.Insert(0, transform.position);
    lastrotation.Insert(0, transform.rotation);

    Move();

    UpdateSegments();

}

//removed move function(uses rb.addforce and rb.addrelativetorque

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = (force * transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void addnewSegment()
{
    GameObject newsegment = Instantiate(segment, lastpos[spawndelay * i], lastrotation[spawndelay * i]);
    segments.Add(newsegment);
    newsegment.GetComponent<SegmentScript>().spawnint = spawndelay * i;
    i++;

}

void UpdateSegments()
{

    foreach(GameObject intsegment in segments)
    {
        intsegment.transform.position = lastpos[intsegment.GetComponent<SegmentScript>().spawnint];
        intsegment.transform.rotation = lastrotation[intsegment.GetComponent<SegmentScript>().spawnint];
    }
}

private IEnumerator spawnseg()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    addnewSegment();
    StartCoroutine(spawnseg());
}
```

Basiclly i save all the last positions in a list, then have the objects just move to the next spot in the list.
However the segments seem to be jittering around in their place even when going straight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you record your current position, add a force in `Move();` and then set the position in `UpdateSegemnts(){}` back to the saved position. That takes time and might explain the jitter.

To be honest it's kind of difficult to give you a clear answer with the things you provided so far.

But as a beginning please don't call a Coroutine from inside a Coroutine. Use InvokeRepeating.

I think you are using 2 different pathes to create a game like this at the same time. The physics way and the "fake way". I.E. you can use hinge joints to go with the physics way and not save any positions and rotations whatsoever or you can fake it and use animations for rotation and movement and record the positions.

I appreciate the effort to compress the script for your question but it only makes things difficult. Please use comments especially when accessing another script like `<SegmentScript>` and explain why you are doing what you are doing and please include the Move function.